# breadth first search in c using algorithm given by cormen

Tags: c

i tried out algorithm as specified by cormen for bfs,

the code is:

```
    bfs(int s){
     int i;
     int u,v;
     struct edge *e;
     graph[s].colour=1;
     graph[s].d=0;
     graph[s].pre=-1;

enqueue(s);
while (isempty()!=1){
    u=dequeue();
    printf("%d\t",u);
    e=graph[u].edgePtr;
    while(e!=NULL)
    {       
        v=e->vertexIndex;
        if(graph[v].colour==WHITE){
            graph[v].colour=GRAY;
            graph[v].d=graph[u].d+1;
            graph[v].pre=u;

            enqueue(v);
            e=e->edgePtr;
        }
        graph[u].colour=BLACK;
    }
}
 }
```

i m getting an infinite loop...can someone tell me where exactly i m going wrong??

Comment: How does it compare the algorithm you read? (Hint: some of the readers on SO don't own [Introduction To Algorithms](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0262032937), I being one of them).

Comment: No — it isn't an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  You've got a global variable `graph` that we can't see defined or populated.  Your indentation is erratic (don't use tabs on SO; it leads to problems).  We can't see your queue management functions.

Comment: You assign graph[s].colour to 1 to start. But then use color values of WHITE and GRAY to indicate a visitor status.  So it's confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up your closing `}`. As a consequence, you only move on to the next edge if the color is `WHITE`, and stay on the same edge in an infinite loop if the color of `u` is non-`WHITE`. The correct form should look like this:

```
bfs(int s){
  // …
  while (isempty()!=1){
    u=dequeue();
    // …
    while(e!=NULL) {       
      v=e->vertexIndex;
      if (graph[v].colour==WHITE){
        graph[v].colour=GRAY;
        graph[v].d=graph[u].d+1;
        graph[v].pre=u;

        enqueue(v);
      } // end if WHITE
      e=e->edgePtr; // update e for all colours!
    } // end loop over all edges e
    graph[u].colour=BLACK;
  } // end loop while queue is not empty
} // end function
```